# Error in Postman i.e. Could not get any response

Tags: postman

**Could not get any response**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHsoj.png)
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:3000/api/employees.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General

Comment: Are you sure localhost is up? what is the endpoint ? also try port 8080

Answer (score -1):

Go to C:/
Create a data folder
in data, folder create another db folder.
open cmd c:/mongoDB/server/bin
Type command mongod(used to start the server)

open another cmd,
c:/mongoDB/server/bin
Type command mongo